# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
def beautify(arg):
    # Adds a "thousands separator" — for readability purposes.
    return format(arg, ',d').replace(',', '.')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_window_size(800, 660)
driver.get('https://vipto.de/')
print('[!] Solve the captcha...')
captcha = True

while captcha:
    try:
        driver.find_element("xpath",
            '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/button'
        ) .click()
    except (
        common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException,
        common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException
    ):
        continue
    driver.set_window_position(-10000, 0)
    print('[!] Running...')
    captcha = False
# Pastes the URL into the "Enter video URL" textbox.
driver.find_element("xpath",
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/form/div/input'
).send_keys(VIDEO_URL)

while True:
    # Clicks the "Search" button.
    driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/form/div/div/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)

    try:
        # Clicks the "Send Views" button.
        driver.find_element("xpath",
            '/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/button'
        ).click()
    except common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        driver.quit()
        os.system('cls')
        print(
            f'[>] TikTok Video URL: {VIDEO_URL}\n'
            '[!] Solve the captcha...\n'
            '[!] Invalid URL.'
        )
        break
    else:
        views_sent += 1000
        os.system(f'title [TikTok Automated Viewbot] - Views Sent: {beautify(views_sent)}')

        seconds = 62
        while seconds > 0:
            seconds -= 1
            os.system(
```

I've already changed the "elements", nothing has resolved the error, I need help with this 'click' error

Comment: Missing a lot of context. Please add the rest of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Better provide full context. Based on your piece of code, it shows element is not found. Double check if the "xpath" is correct. You can try *find_element_by_css_selector()*